# Unable To Lock Store This Is Usually A Result Of Some Other Neo4j Kernel Running Using The Same Store

Tags: java, spring, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I am making an app using Spring and Neo4j but whenever i try to launch the app i keep getting this error. I am sure there is no  other program running. Here is the error

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'graphDatabaseService': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to lock store [C:\Users\Anthony\Documents\tomcat7\apache-tomcat-7.0.40\bin\target\config-test\neostore], this is usually a result of some other Neo4j kernel running using the same store.
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:288)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1045)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:949)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:487)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:626)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:651)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:599)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:665)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:518)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:459)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1008)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Answer (score 0):

Spring is trying to initialize the GraphDatabaseService during startup. `C:\Users\Anthony\Documents\tomcat7\apache-tomcat-7.0.40\bin\target\config-test\neostore` is the default location configured. It makes sense to have the neo4j db in a directory outside of the tomcat folder structure. I suggest you find the spring config file where the GDB is being initialized and changes it to something like below

```
<neo4j:config storeDirectory="C:\home\neo4j-db"/>
```

Comment: Okay, i will try this. Also would it have an adverse effect on anything if i deleted the config-test folder?

Comment: Upon changing the directory i am still getting the same error

Comment: @IceNine See if the tomcat process has "write/read" permission to the new directory. there should also be a root cause somewhere in he exception chain. post that

Answer (score 0):

As the exception says, this is usually thrown when another instance of Neo4j is using the same store. By construction, you cannot have more than one. So either you have another process that is using the store, or your store may have remained in a locked state after a crash (or unexpected shutdown).

If you are sure there isn't another process that is accessing the store, try to remove manually the NEO4j_HOME/data/graph.db/lock and NEO4j_HOME/data/graph.db/store_lock files before you launch the app.